# Writing on an output file

Tags: java

I am stuck on this part where it does not write to an output file

the first class is contact I had to modify this is not my class is the authors class
I just had to use it

```
    //********************************************************************  
// Contact.java Author: Lewis/Loftus  
//  
// Represents a phone contact.  
//********************************************************************  
public class Contact implements Comparable  
{  
 private String firstName, lastName, phone;  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  // Constructor: Sets up this contact with the specified data.  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  public Contact (String first, String last, String telephone)  
  {  
    firstName = first;  
    lastName = last;  
    phone = telephone;  
  }  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  // Returns a description of this contact as a string.  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  public String toString ()  
  {  
    return lastName + ", " + firstName + "\t" + phone;  
  }  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  // Returns true if the first and last names of this contact match  
  // those of the parameter.  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  public boolean equals (Object other)  
  {  
   return (lastName.equals(((Contact)other).getLastName()) &&  
   firstName.equals(((Contact)other).getFirstName()));  
  }  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  // Uses both last and first names to determine ordering.  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  public int compareTo (Object other)  
  {  
   int result;  
   String otherFirst = ((Contact)other).getFirstName();  
   String otherLast = ((Contact)other).getLastName();  

   if (lastName.equals(otherLast))  

      result = firstName.compareTo(otherFirst);  
   else  

      result = lastName.compareTo(otherLast);  

    return result;  
  }  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  // First name accessor.  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  public String getFirstName ()  
  {  
    return firstName;  
  }  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  // Last name accessor.  
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------  
  public String getLastName ()  
  {  
    return lastName;  
  }  
}
```

this class oes the sorting this is fine. it does the sorting no prblem

```
    public class Sorting {  

    public static void bubbleSortRecursive(Comparable[] data, int n)   
    {  

        if (n < 2)   
        {  
            return;  
        }  
        else  
        {  

            int lastIndex = n - 1;  

            for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)   
            {  
                if (data[i].compareTo(data[i + 1]) > 0)   
                { //swap check  

                    Comparable tmp = data[i];  
                    data[i] = data[i + 1];  
                    data[i + 1] = tmp;  
                }  
            }  

            bubbleSortRecursive(data, lastIndex);  
        }  
    }  

    public static void selectionSortRecursive(Comparable[] data, int n)   
    {  

        if (n < 2)   
        {  
            return;  
        }   
        else   
        {  

            int lastIndex = n - 1;  
            int largestIndex = lastIndex;  

            for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)   
            {  
                if (data[i].compareTo(data[largestIndex]) > 0)   
                {  
                    largestIndex = i;  
                }  
            }  

            if (largestIndex != lastIndex)   
            { //swap check  
                Comparable tmp = data[lastIndex];  
                data[lastIndex] = data[largestIndex];  
                data[largestIndex] = tmp;  
            }  

            selectionSortRecursive(data, n - 1);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

this is the part I need help with. It is not outputing to he p4output.txt, i dont know what the problem is.

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileWriter;  
import java.io.IOException;  


public class TestProject4 {  

    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {  

        doBubbleSortRecursive();  

        System.out.println();  
        System.out.println();  

        doSelectionSortRecursive();  

    }  
    private static void doBubbleSortRecursive()  
    {  
        Contact[] contacts = createContacts();  

        System.out.println("Before bubbleSortRecursive(): ");  
        for (int i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)  
        System.out.println(contacts[i].toString());  


        Sorting.bubbleSortRecursive(contacts, contacts.length);  

        System.out.println("\nAfter bubbleSortRecursive(): ");  
        for (int i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)  
        System.out.println(contacts[i].toString());  
    }  

    private static void doSelectionSortRecursive()   
    {  
        Contact[] contacts = createContacts();  


        System.out.println("Before selectionSortRecursive(): ");  
        for (int i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)  
        System.out.println(contacts[i].toString());  

        Sorting.selectionSortRecursive(contacts, contacts.length);  

        System.out.println("\nAfter selectionSortRecursive(): ");  
        for (int i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)  
        System.out.println(contacts[i].toString());  
    }  

    private static void printContacts(Contact[] contacts)  
    {  

        try   
        {  

        // this part I need help with it is not outputing in the text file   
                    File file = new File("p4output.txt");  
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());  
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);  

            for (Contact contact : contacts)  
             {  
                bw.write(contact.toString());       
             }              
              bw.close();  
        }  

        catch (IOException e)   
        {  
           e.printStackTrace();  
        }  

       System.out.println("\t" + contacts);  
    }  
    public static Contact[] createContacts()   
    {  
        return new Contact[]   
        {  
            new Contact("John"  , "Smith" , "610-555-7384"),  
            new Contact("Sarah" , "Barnes"   , "215-555-3827"),  
            new Contact("Mark"  , "Riley", "333-333-3333"),  
            new Contact("Laura"   , "Getz"  ,"663-555-3984"),  
            new Contact("Larry"  , "Smith"  , "464-555-3489"),  
            new Contact("Frank"  , "Phelps" , "322-555-2284"),  
            new Contact("Mario"    , "Guzman" , "804-555-9066"),  
            new Contact("Marsha"    , "Grant" , "243-555-2837"),  
        };  
     }  
 }
```

Comment: First lesson. Please repeat after me: *Java is not JavaScript*.

Comment: Comments should be concise, not ascii art.

Comment: Why would you add those 2 classes that aren't directly related to the problem?

Comment: I recommend you write a very short program (based on the above) where you try to write to file, and see if it works. If it doesn't, post it and we'll help you figure out why. Often, just that exercise will help you solve your own problem.

Comment: You never call the printContacts() method...?  You would have to call the method for it to print the information to the file.

Comment: Do you think the problem is with writing the file, or is your contacts method broken? You should be able to answer that question with a few simple debug lines...

Comment: By the way, you just need to pass `file` when creating the `FileWriter`: `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);`. Also, as stated by @torquestomp you never use the `printContacts` method.

Comment: Your code for writing to file is in the `printContacts` method. You need to invoke/call the method for it to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to Eclipse, you never call/use `printContacts(Contact[] contacts);` method

[image]

Your `printContacts(Contact[] contacts);` contains the statements to write a file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to call the function printContacts() in your program. Try calling it after you do your contact creation and sorting.

It might look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)   
{  

    doBubbleSortRecursive();  

    System.out.println();  
    System.out.println();  

    doSelectionSortRecursive();  
    printContacts(contactArray);//inserted code
}
```

Also, when you call your sorting methods, doSelectionSortRecursive(), you don't return the list of contacts. Make a return statement for it and then put the contact array into your printContacts function.

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)   
{  

    doBubbleSortRecursive();  

    System.out.println();  
    System.out.println();  

    Contact[] contacts = doSelectionSortRecursive();  
    printContacts(contacts);
}  

public static Contact[] doSelectionSortRecursive(){
    Contact[] contacts = createContacts();
    //your sorting code
    return contacts;
}
```

Using this method allows you to get the array of contacts from the method once it has been sorted.